# trouble in reading word separated by '|'

Tags: c

I tried to read the following line of 3  words in a file:

fruit|apple|lemon

```
char *type, *type2, *type3;
```

using this:                `fscanf(file, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%s", type, type2, type3);`

but I am getting seg fault. anyone can help?

Comment: How are `type`, `type2` and `type3` declared?

Comment: Hint: Your pointers point nowhere.

Comment: oh, so I should use something like type[100]?

Comment: Yes. And a formatter like `%99s` that limits the input length to avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: Use `char *type=malloc(10)` or `char type[10]`,depending on what size you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to allocate some space for the results.  It appears from your example that type, type2, and type3 are all null.  You need to point them at some storage on the heap or stack, like:

char type[64];

however be wary of buffer overflow here.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c) for advice on how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `fscanf()` statement to this.It works.But make sure `file` is of type `FILE*`.Else if it is a string,you have to use `sscanf()`:

```
fscanf(file, "%[^|]%*c%[^|]%*c%s", type, type2, type3);

//sscanf(file, "%[^|]%*c%[^|]%*c%s", type, type2, type3);


//Demo for the sscanf() case


#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *file="fruit|apple|lemon",type[10],type2[10],type3[10];

sscanf(file, "%[^|]%*c%[^|]%*c%s", type, type2, type3);
printf("%s,%s,%s",type,type2,type3);
}
```

**Output** `fruit,apple,lemon`